# Disable select options based on three character string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have five select option drop down lists like below:

```
<select id="select1">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="ALB - Joe Bloggs">ALB - Joe Bloggs</option>
    <option value="ALG - Fred Perry">ALB - Joe Bloggs</option>
    etc
</select>
```

What I would like to do, using the jQuery `.change()` event is get the current three character nationality i.e ALB and disable all subsequent select options in the four other drop downs.

The idea is to allow selection of 5 players whereby you cannot have a player with the same nationality. Unfortunately I have no control over the rendered html.

UPDATE:
I have been trying the following: http://jsfiddle.net/Webby2014/bA3Tb/

Comment: What you have tried??? Show something.

Comment: @Manwal sorry! I've updated my post with the js fiddle, it's a little messy!!!

Comment: ur fiddle is working fine,wats the issue?

Comment: you can use jquery split function to split the value by " ". and match.

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird the js fiddle doesn't disable any options for the other drop downs. I can only get it to display an alert if a duplicate nationality exists.

Comment: option value should be only two or max. five digits ,else Logic becomes unnecesarry comeplex

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird like I mentioned I had no control over this. It's a plugin which renders the form in wordpress. I am just trying to add additional validation of the selections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:  Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/bA3Tb/3/

You can do the counting or whatever else, this just makes sure that values become disabled for other dropdowns and re-enabled when `unselected`

```
$(function () {
    var previous;

    $("select").on('focus', function () {
        // Store the current value on focus and on change
        previous = this.value;
    }).on('change', function () {
        // Get the filter value
        var filterVal = $(this).val().substr(0, 3);
        var selector = 'option[value^="' + filterVal + '"]';
        others = $('select').not(this).find(selector);
        others.prop('disabled', true);

        // Now loop through and enable previous
        var oldFilterVal = previous.substr(0, 3);
        var oldSelector = 'option[value^="' + oldFilterVal + '"]';
        $('select').find(oldSelector).prop('disabled', false);
    });
});
```

Comment: This is immense! Exactly what I need - however, I would like to split the drop downs into two separate checks players 1 to 5 and players (6 to 10). How easy is it to amend the code to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I have added a class on each `select` input either `group1` or `group2`.  Then modified the listeners and duplicated them http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/bA3Tb/4/

Answer (score 2):

Inside of your change handler, loop over each `select`, then find the matching `option` in each of the other `selects`, and disable it:

```
// inside of your change handler
$('select').each(function() {

    var currentValue = this.value.split(' ').shift();

    $('select').not(this).find('option').filter(function() {
      return this.value.split(' ').shift() === currentValue;
    }).prop('disabled', true);

});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7EJ2c/)

Answer (score 1):

Try with filter:

```
$('select').change(function () {
    var val = this.value.substr(0, 3);
    $('select').not(this).find('option').filter(function () {
        return this.textContent.indexOf(val) !== -1
    }).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bA3Tb/2/)

Comment: SUPERB! Can this be tweaked so it only applies to specific drop downs on the page?

Comment: You can use same class names then or you can change your selector to this: `$('select[name^="item_meta"]')`.

Comment: The only problem with this is that if the user changes their selection, the previously selected option will remain disabled in all other selects

Comment: then we can enable all the options first then we'll try to disable it.

Comment: but then only one option will ever be disabled

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a better way, but the easiest is to loop over all selects each time one changes

Answer (score 1):

`^` [**Jquery selector**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/): Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string.

**Short solution:** You can do this like following also:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {

    $('option[disabled]').prop('disabled', false);
    var currentValue = $(this).val().split(' ').shift();
    $('select').not(this).find('option[value^="'+currentValue+'"]').prop('disabled', true);

});
```

[**Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/W3CGy/2/)

Comment: That'll disable the option in the select where it is selected

Comment: You're disabling options in **all** selects where the value matches, including the one where it has been selected

Comment: @billyonecan help me with this. Why `.not(this)` is not working here?

Comment: because `this` is a `select`, and you're working with a collection of `options`

Comment: Thanks a lot @billyonecan. I have fixed it. Updated ans also